# How to move one of the tabPanel to the right the webpage in Shiny-App

Tags: javascript, html, css, r, shiny

I have the following Shiny App.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyApp(
  shinyUI(
    navbarPage("X-men",
               tabPanel("Plot"),
               tabPanel("Summary" )
            )),
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {})
               )
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Which produce things like this:

[image]

As stated in that image. How can I move `Summary` tab panel to the right?

---

**Update**

After HubertL suggestion :

[image]

Notice the distortion and it's not "Summary" which get moved to the right.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the `width` of `nav-bar` and set its `first-child` position to `float:right` :

```
shinyApp(ui = shinyUI(
    navbarPage("X-men", selected="Plot",
               tabPanel("Summary" ),
               tabPanel("Plot"),
               tags$head(tags$style('.navbar-nav {width: 95%;}
                                    .navbar-nav :first-child{float:right}'))
                   )),
  server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {}))
```

#### Edit :

Added `selected="Plot"` to keep Plot as the active `tabset`
[image]

Comment: It does on my setup

Comment: I'm sorry it doesn't on yours

Comment: it also works on firefox... Have you used my whole code? (reversing tab order?)

Comment: Ok. My bad. Is there a way to make it work on `fixedPage()` context?

Comment: if I have multiple `tabPanel`'s and `navbarMenu`'s , how do I get a very specific one to move to the right?

Comment: Hello @road_to_quantdom, please feel free to ask a new question with reproducible code.